# I want to use a RewriteRule in .htaccess to allow subfolders

Tags: .htaccess

We have a url mydomain.com/events that needs to include a country code just before th events folder like this mycomain.com/uk/events. The country could be any number of different codes. I want to use  a RewriteRule like:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/events/*.* /events/*.*
```

so any any url like these will work:

```
mydomain.com/uk/events
mydomain.com/uk/events/index.php
mydomain.com/uk/events/list-events.php?s=12
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Place your htaccess file along with your domain folder(not inside it beside it).

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^/]*)/(?:[^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.*?\.php(?:\?[^=]+=\d+)?)?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2%3 [L]
```

Comment: I have made slight changes in Rules, so please use updated ones.

Comment: @Graham Holdaway, could you please do let me know if my answer has helped you?

Comment: Sorry, I tried this and didn't work. I'm not sure I understand your comment "Place your htaccess file along with your domain folder(not inside it beside it)."
The htaccess file as far as I know can only exist in the domain route folder.

Comment: @Graham Holdaway, Could you please do let me know what is sample url you are hitting? And what error are you getting?

Comment: sample url would be ukeas . com / ng / events3 /   This url works fine, but anything with a page name after it like  ukeas . com / ng / events3 / index.php doesn't work